# Is it possible to make kataifi dough (by yourself or starting from filo dough)?

Tags: dough, dessert, pastry, greek-cuisine

I really like the thready structure in this dish. But when I look for recipes, they all ask for a box of kataifi dough. I haven't found this in regular supermarkets (I haven't been to greek stores), so I was thinking if I could make it myself.

Would it be best to buy filo dough (which is thinner than if you would make it yourself) and shred/cut it; or to make filo dough yourself (so you would have longer pieces than store-bought dough) and cut/shred it?

How do you shred it exactly? And how would can you replicate the correct form of kataifi (like a roll)?

Comment: Here's a video showing how it's made (towards the end): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-b5o6jwhTw&feature=related

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am afraid that it is quite hard to prepare it yourself. And you don't start from phylo dough.

Kataifi is not shredded, it is spun. You need a hot metal wheel for that. It is made from a batter which is thrown on the wheel, and because the wheel is spun, it bakes on the wheel in threads. You need not only the instruments (this wheel), but also quite a bit of experience to throw it in even threads. Kataifi makers are a popular attraction on middle-eastern markets. If you can't visit one, you have to visit an ethnic grocery store to buy the prepared kataifi noodles.

Comment: Could you give me a link to a site that says something about that wheel? I've found http://www.monkeysee.com/play/10981-preparing-kataifi ; there is some explanation how they make the dough at about 1:15 (please, don't pay attention to the horrible pronounciation of kataifi).

Comment: Sorry, I can't. I tried to find a video of it, but failed. I know that this is how it is made, because I've watched it happen at a market. Also, the woman in this video makes a small mistake too, talking about "made from the same batter as phyllo" - phyllo isn't made from batter, but from a very hard unleavened dough. As for pronunciation, it varies between Middle Eastern languages anyway, I write and pronounce it as "kadaif".

Comment: Is the hot wheel hot enough to *dry* the dough, or it is very hot and it *cooks* the dough? It is a dry wheel, or the dough is fried?

Comment: @akiross it is a bit hard to make the distinction, as irreversible changes happen in a heated dough long before it can be declared cooked through. But if I have to pick one, I would call it baked, not just dried. The wheel is as hot as a crepe maker, IIRC, and kadaif filaments are much thinner than crepes.

Comment: More of all i would like to know what is the hot surface made of? Is it iron, steel or copper? Id love to know more on how is it made like the semi automatic machine if anyone has any Knowledge of it...

Comment: I know this post is several years old, but if somebody is still looking at it, here's a video of it being made. https://youtu.be/NV19r48LtwA

Answer (score -1):

There are machines for this. You can buy a kadayif(kunefe) dessert pattern maker, it is available online. However, it is somewhat expensive, around 140 USD.